# Hidden section in header

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, koma-script

My problem is that I don't know how to include `\section*{Some Title}` in `\rightmark`. Currently `\rightmark` is working fine for all types of pages e.g. list of figures, list of tables, table of content etc. But when there is a page wiith `\section*{Some Title}`, `\rightmark` is empty.

Any suggestions how to solve my problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc]{scratcl}

\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{Musterhausarbeit\\ \rightmark{} \\ \markboth{#1}{#1}}
\ofoot{\thepage}

\renewcommand*{\titlepagestyle}{empty}

\addtokomafont{section}{\clearpage}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \listoffigures
    \newpage

    \listoftables
    \newpage

    \section*{Some title}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Some title}
    \newpage

    \section{Some more title}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't use `\markboth` inside the header with an argument. The header macro doesn't take an argument and therefore doesn't know what `#1` represents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like inserting the ToC entry manually, add the right mark manually using

```
\section*{Some title}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Some title}
\markright{Some title}
```

or via `\markboth{<left>}{<right>}`.

This process can be automated if needed.

Comment: As the class is `scrartcl`, there is `\addsec`.

Comment: @egreg: Great! `\addsec{<title>}` is similar to the appropriate section, ToC and header entries.

Comment: I should have said that I compile my latex file with Pandoc. Is it possible to declare `\markboth` to have also `\section*`?

Comment: @Bene: I don't understand what you mean by "`\markboth` to have also `\section*`"? Can you provide a *complete*, *minimal* Markdown document (on [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/)).

Comment: It's just that I can't add `\markboth{<left>}{<right>}` or `\addsec{<title>}` to my latex file. Because `section*` gets inserted via pandoc and I need to have a variable where I have both section types.

Comment: @Bene: Aahh, so you need it to be automated so that `\section*{<title>}` turns into `\addsec{<title>}`.  Are the document class options (`a4paper,listof=totoc,bibliography=totoc`) added manually or automatically? Are you able to remove `listof=totoc` and `bibliography=totoc`)? If that's the case, one can make *all` \section*` default to `\addsec`.

Comment: Yes, thats possible. How would I do that?

Comment: @Bene: See if you can make [this minimal example](http://pastebin.com/tDuqQgW5) work with Pandoc by adding content to the `header-includes` area... I think.